# How to compare two variables of the model with Thymeleaf Standard Expression Syntax?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set the `selected` option's attribute with thymeleaf + springMVC as shown below:

(`item.codItem` and `defaultCodItem` are Long)

```
<select id="selItems">
<th:block th:each="item : ${myItems}">
    <option value="564" th:value="${item.codItem}" th:selected="(${item.codItem} eq ${defaultCodItem})? 'selected' : '' "
        th:text="${item.codItem} + ' || ' + ${defaultCodItem}">  564 || ?
    </option>
</th:block>
</select>
```

But the result is...

```
<select id="selItems">
    <option selected="selected" value="455">11/2014 - 455 || 450</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="450">450 || 450</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="452">452 || 450</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="457">457 || 450</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="453">453 || 450</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="454">454 || 450</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="451">451 || 450</option>
</select>
```

When I expected this:

```
<select id="selItems">
    <option selected="" value="455">11/2014 - 455 || 450</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="450">450 || 450</option>
    <option selected="" value="452">452 || 450</option>
    <option selected="" value="457">457 || 450</option>
    <option selected="" value="453">453 || 450</option>
    <option selected="" value="454">454 || 450</option>
    <option selected="" value="451">451 || 450</option>
</select>
```

So, how should I compare `item.codItem` with `defaultCodItem` in the template to set `selected` attribute correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Thymeleaf documentation :

> The Standard Dialect includes attributes that allow you to set these attributes by evaluating a condition, so that if evaluated to
>   true, the attribute will be set to its fixed value, and if evaluated to false, the attribute will not be set

*selected* is one of them . I think you should write the condition simply as :

```
th:selected="${item.codItem} eq ${defaultCodItem}"
```

I guess your current line does not work as expected because non null values are evaluated to true (such as your empty string)

Comment: Please add justification when downvoting